# Google Maps Android API V2 Showing Resteraunt On Map Without Using Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there any way to show local restaurants on the my map without using the Places API and if not what is the easiest way to overlay the points onto my map in my android app using Places API ?

Thank You

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: is there a way to do this so its populated from google though as in an easy way to implement place